Unit Testing AWS Lambda function for DynamoDB using moto 5.x.x
In the latest moto version @mock_dynamodb and @mock_dynamodb2 are depricated and removed. Can someone please share an example of mocking and unit testing dynamodb operation from AWS Lambda using moto. Found a few examples using @mock_aws, but nothing concrete.

Are you upgrading from v4 and v5, and are you running into a specific problem? A code sample of what you have so far will be helpful.

I am creating a new application.
Python version 3.11, boto3 version 1.34, moto version 5.0.6.
When I use
from moto import mock_dynamodb2
@mock_dynamodb2 def test_lambda_handler():
I get the error ImportError: cannot import name 'mock_dynamodb2' from 'moto'

@BertBlommers https://github.com/getmoto/moto/issues/5366

The behaviour is mostly the same between v4 and v5 - you just have to replace mock_dynamodb with mock_aws.
There are a ton of unit tests in the Moto project that you can use as examples though:
https://github.com/getmoto/moto/blob/master/tests/test_dynamodb/test_dynamodb.py
